# Return and print value passed through php script from javascript object using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, object

i have the following code:
**Javascript object:**

```
 var getDBresults = (function () {  
    function getResult(url,TableName ,callback){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'table':TableName,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                callback(data);
                console.log(data)

            },
            error: function(){}
        });
    }   
    return {
        getAllVideoes: function(){
            getResult("getAllResults.php", "videoer", function(data){
                return data;
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

**simple php script:**

```
<?php

    $tableName = $_REQUEST['table'];

    echo $tableName;
?>
```

**My js command for fetching(seperate script ofc):**

```
    var obj = getDBresults;
    var data = obj.getAllVideoes();
console.log(data)
```

My issue is with the callback function. It wont output anything and it doesn't seem to be running at all.. Had this issue for quite som time now and i just cant figure it out.. Is there anything i'v been missing? All help is apriciated! Sorry for my spelling btw.

Comment: On the JS side, have you tried using a debugger (firebug, et al.) to make sure the callback is being triggered?  Also, I'd add a logging statement to your error callback.  I'm not sure about your PHP, it doesn't look right to me, but I'll let someone who knows more about PHP comment on that :)

Comment: _“and it doesn't seem to be running at all”_ – don’t _assume_ what “seems” to be happening or, not – __verify__ it. Your browser has a bunch of developer tools build in to debug stuff like this, so familiarize yourself with how to use them.

Comment: yeah, im using firebug and the callback is not running. thats why i thought it might be a syntax problem. thx for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ajax is expecting

```
`dataType: 'json',`
```

json output from your php script

you are returning html/plaintext data

```
`echo $tableName;`
```

try `json_encode`

```
echo json_encode(array($tableName));
```

result is  not in JSON format, so when jQuery fails to parse it,

You can catch the error with ajax's `error:` callback function

Comment: btw, do you know how to get the value passed to mye other js script?var obj = getDBresults;   var data = obj.getAllVideoes(); console.log(data) still results in undefined

Comment: please create a new question a post your code so can check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302060/returning-value-from-javascript-object